# Typescript type of optional property within complex type object

Tags: typescript, option-type

I'm trying to get the `type` of an optional property found within a complex type as shown in the example below. It's probably simple to solve but I haven't able to find the solution.

```
type ComplexType = {
    lvl0: {
        title: string;
        lvl1: {
            title: string;
            lvl2?: {
                title: string;
                lvl3: {
                    title: string;
                }
            }[]
        }[]
    }[]
}

type lvl3Type = ComplexType["lvl0"][0]["lvl1"][0]["lvl2"][0]["lvl3"];
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrmgXigbwCgoSpkA3ZABgC4DjTHgBLYVOgZ2ACdmA7AOYBuBoxIVkARjpExcqCzYROPfsNHzxlAEwB%20GRs1NW7KF16CRR%20RIDMB69cWnzaq48YBfQ-M8BtAF0fEn8gr0DCb0JQSDJKWyxYvHgkVExsPwAiCSpMgL8qfOzKSTyCooltMsKsuzyRIA)

There's an error with the last `[0]`. How would I get the `lvl3Type` to resolve?

Comment: @Hyetigran Yes. It errors. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrmgXigbwCgoSpkA3ZABgC4DjTHgBLYVOgZ2ACdmA7AOYBuBoxIVkARjpExcqCzYROPfsNHzxlAEwB+GRs1NW7KF16CRR+RIDMB69cWnzaq48YBfQ-M8BtAF0fEn8gr0DCb0JQSDJKWyxYvHgkVExsPwAiCSpMgL8qfOzKSTyCooltPIBCcqy7PJEgA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error, emphasis mine:

> Property '0' does not exist on type '{ title: string; lvl3: { title: string; }; }[] **| undefined**'.

As in your question title, `lvl2` is optional: it's defined as `lvl2?`. If `lvl2` is undefined, `lvl2[0]` will throw an error, so TypeScript is telling you that you can't apply `[0]` to a type that might be undefined.

Use the [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) [`NonNullable<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to avoid the issue and get the type you want.

```
type lvl3Type =
    NonNullable<ComplexType["lvl0"][0]["lvl1"][0]["lvl2"]>[0]["lvl3"];
```

Unfortunately you'll need a utility like this instead of `!`, as [kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3) noted in the comments: The `!` only applies to expressions, not types, to indicate that the expression *value* is not null or undefined.

Comment: Ah, got it. So `NonNullable` has to be used instead of bang operator?

Comment: The `!` operator appears in an expression to assert that the expression's value will not be null/undefined; you can only use it in an expression, not in a type.